# Android Bluetooth issues with high number of paired devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

We're running into an issue with Android (4.4 and 5.0) where the OS seems to forget a paired device and requests to pair again (notification pops up). This issue seems to happen when we have a high number of paired devices (close to 50 bands).

Any suggestions on where we could look in the AOSP code? We sell a solution that includes the Android hardware (Nexus 9/10) and we have flexibility in terms of rooting, etc.